# Caret Getting Error: nrow(x) == n is not TRUE

Tags: r, r-caret

Getting the error `Error: nrow(x) == n is not TRUE` when I am using Caret, can anyone help. See example below

Get Wisconsin Breast Cancer dataset and load required libraries

```
library(dplyr)
library(caret)
library(mlbench)
data(BreastCancer)

myControl = trainControl(
method = "cv", number = 5,
repeats = 5, verboseIter = TRUE
)

breast_cancer_y <- BreastCancer %>%
  dplyr::select(Class)

breast_cancer_x <- BreastCancer %>%
  dplyr::select(-Class)
```

Also apply median imputation to model for missing data

```
model <- train(
  x = breast_cancer_x,
  y = breast_cancer_y,
  method = "glmnet",
  trControl = myControl,
  preProcess = "medianImpute"
  )
```

Getting this error -

> Error: nrow(x) == n is not TRUE

Answer (score 0):

Here, `breast_cancer_y` is a data.frame. Consider using `y = breast_cancer_y$Class` in the `train` function.

You also have a character column in `breast_cancer_x`; the `Id` columns.

I am still getting some other error messages after fixing these. These appear related to pre-processing and control.

Comment: The new error message is related to a different issue.

Comment: Is it something to do with the data containing factors?

Comment: I think you should have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I do not know about `glmnet`, I'd think some of the columns need to be numeric for it. I guess you should try inserting making some of the columns numeric etc.